# How can I restore a deleted directory entry on an ext4 file system?

Tags: linux, directory, ext4, data-recovery

I was in the process of doing a `fsck` on an ext4 filesystem on my NAS, where it hit a hard error and quit (unfortunately I've since lost the error message).  When I remounted the volume right after to see if it was damaged (read-only, of course), I found that I had lost nearly all the data on the drive (nearly 8TB, and of course, I don't have a backup of most of it... I know, I know). One directory off the root is present (and seems to have all its contents), but none of the other directories in the root are present anymore.  There were a few files in `/lost+found`, but it's a tiny tiny fraction of the files on the disk.

I've been trying various data recovery tools on the disk, and found the `fls` program from SleuthKit (and some helpful scripts that use it).  It seems to "find" the root directories, but shows them as deleted:

```
d/- * 0:    home
d/- * 0:    photos
d/- * 0:    music
d/- * 0:    games
d/- * 0:    books
d/- * 0:    docker-registry
d/- * 0:    cache
```

(The `*` means deleted, and `0` is the inode number, which appears to have been zeroed out by `fsck`.)

Unfortunately, the `-r` option to `fls` can't recurse into deleted directory trees, per its manpage.  Is there a way to somehow "undelete" these directory entries?  My hope is that the metadata in the directory entries is still present, and `fsck` merely got confused and deleted whatever points to the root entries, and that if I could somehow restore them, I could get `fls` to recursively find all the old contents.

### Other things I've tried

I've tried other tools, like `ext4magic` and `extundelete`, but those appear to just look in the journal for recently-deleted entries, and finds nothing there (I assume when `fsck` modifies the filesystem, it bypasses the journal).

I'm running `photorec` on the disk (which it turns out can recover much more than photos these days), but it's estimating it'll take 2000 hours (over 11 weeks) to go over the entire disk.  After running for about 8 hours, it's found around 45GB of data across 65k files, but they of course have useless or mostly-useless names and no directory structure; sifting through the relatively small number of files found found so far could easily take months.

I've also read through the list of commands offered by `debugfs`, but I don't really see anything that would be useful here, but it's possible I've just misunderstood some of its functionality.

I tried `foremost`, but it segfaulted a minute or so after it started looking at the drive, with no useful output beforehand.  `scalpel`, which is based on `foremost`, just prints its startup message and then immediately exits with status 1 without telling me what's wrong.

### Complications

The volume is around 12TB in size, and is part of two RAID5 arrays joined together with LVM2.  Unfortunately I don't have the available space anywhere to make an image of the filesystem.  I've been using read-only recovery tools up until now, but if there is a way to recover the root directory entries, I'll likely have to do the modification to the actual disk.

My scratch space for recovery is a 6TB volume that I managed to scrounge up; if `photorec` actually does find everything that's lost, it'll run out of space before it's done.

### In conclusion...

So, to recap my question here at the bottom: is there a way to "undelete" the directory entries that `fls` has found off the root, in the hope that their recursive contents might be valid and usable?

Comment: Wow!  The only thing that comes to my mind is that one could swap out a bad drive on a RAID array with a new drive and let the RAID rebuild it.  I do not know if that applies to all RAID systems or to your system.  But if the problem is not with the drive, but with the directory structure, then I know of no way to recover your data.  I've heard of data recovery services that are available for a price, but I don't know if this kind of data loss can be recovered.

Comment: @StephenDaddona the drives are actually brand new and I've checked to make sure they're in good shape.  I bought these after one of the old drives failed and decided to replace the failed drive as well as upgrade the size. The issue happened when I was running fsck in preparation for using resize2fs to expand the filesystem.